# Why can I bind rvalues to non const reference with a for loop in C++?

Tags: c++, range-based-loop

The logic of the following is confusing me. It compiles ok but the result of `foo` is an rvalue. It is a temporary. Why am I then allowed to get non constant references to items in the container?

https://godbolt.org/z/vEafrE

```
#include <array>

std::array<int,3> foo(){
    return std::array<int,3>{0,1,2};
}

int main(){
    for(int & item: foo())
        item = 0;
}
```

Comment: Probably because the lifetime of the container is long enough to survive the loop contents and thus that reference is safe to use within that loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [range based for loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) has the syntax

```
attr(optional) for ( init-statement(optional)range_declaration : range_expression ) loop_statement
```

and it expands into

```
{
    init-statement
    auto && __range = range_expression ;
    auto __begin = begin_expr ;
    auto __end = end_expr ;
    for ( ; __begin != __end; ++__begin) {
        range_declaration = *__begin;
        loop_statement
    }
}
```

as you can see, the rvalue's lifetime gets extended by `__range`, so it's valid to have lvalue references into the collection `__range` binds to.  Once the loop is over, `__range` will go out of scope destroying the rvalue object that was created.

This is why it works even though you are modifying an object that is destined to be destroyed.